# why some in Facebook when shear link dosn't display selected image

Tags: html, facebook

Why sometimes in Facebook when share a link it doesn't display selected image. Either I specify selected image to share

```
<meta property="og:image:height" content="240">
<meta property="og:image:width" content="440">
<meta property="og:image" content="http://pouchpoint.com/photos/3928716997.jpg" />
```

I use "Open Graph Object Debugger" with this link  http://pouchpoint.com/story_news.php?id=696056274237093 I see this result there is no Image appear in, but when mouse hover it I see path of Image, and when i click on image I see image in my website ???

Can be server side problem or code problem

Comment: If you use exact image path that you pasted here, it is unavailable

Comment: Error 403: You don't have permission to access /photos/3928716997.jpg on this server.

Comment: this is image i path  http://pouchpoint.com/photos/3928716997.jpg !!!!

Comment: ok Why i can see pic when i check up in by path when i past path in web browser ??? 
And thank you for replay Ali

Comment: I receive 403 forbidden message. as a guess, your server may block some certain IP especially Facebook crawler.

Comment: Also check in your control panel if Hotlink protector is off.

Comment: my server also block Ips programmers like PhP Mailer , FileZilla  when something wrong happen so what we do ???

Comment: You're welcome How did you solve it? Hotlink protector?

Comment: If this was a block issue, you should mention that to make it clear for other developers.